# Sorting a list without Linq

Tags: c#, list

Years is IList

```
Data = new SelectList(years.Distinct().ToList().Sort());
```

But it gives syntax error. What to do? I can't use linq.

Comment: Erm... `Distinct()` *is* part of Linq.

Comment: You *are* using linq, and you've not explained what your syntax error is.

Comment: @Polynomial: Not to mention `ToList`.

Comment: `Sort` is defined on `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use Linq? Company policy? Or using an older framework?

Comment: What is the syntax error? Why can't you use LINQ?

Comment: Maybe the Original Poster thinks it's OK to use LINQ to find the distinct elements, but wants to use `List<>.Sort()` for the ordering. It performs better. But since the list is called `years`, assuming it is years from a calendar, one wouldn't think there were very many distinct years.

Comment: @Oded `Enumerable.ToList()` returns the class type `List<>`, not interface type `IList`, so maybe that's not relevant?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - More of a comment to those suggesting `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `Sort()` returns `void` and you pass `void` to `SelectList` constructor.
Your code should look like this:

```
var list = years.Distinct().ToList();
list.Sort();
Data = new SelectList(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use LINQ then you also can't use `Distinct` and `ToList`, so your example code doesn't make sense.

That said, both `List<T>` and `Array` have [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas) [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9771wchs).

Answer (score 0):

Without `Lambda Operator` use

```
List tData = years.Distinct().ToList();

Array.Sort(tData); // Since Array.Sort has a `void` return type.

var Data = new SelectList(tdata);
```

Your `Distinct()` and `ToList()` are `LINQ` Based.

Comment: OP wrote **I can't use linq.**

Comment: @Reniuz: Corrected. Check and upvote if you downvoted.

Comment: You can't mix `List<>` and `Array` like that.